# How do I do a memory dump of all terminated processes?

Tags: server, 10.04, ram, process

I think my subject is pretty spot on. I am on Ubuntu 10.04 on a device with the following specs:

- i5 Processor with 3.30GHz
- 16GB Memory
- 1TB Hard drive
- 1 Gigabyte on board network

I am running 10 users at the same time, as virtual computers (terminals) from NComputing.

I am using around max 8 - 10 GB Memory when computer is running at the fullest. I have the following applications that all the 10 users use simultaneously:

- Firefox
- LibreOffice
- Thunderbird
- Many other folders
- Lot of printing

Around 8:00 - 15:00, my computer (actually a server) is running absolutely fine, then around 15:00 - 15:30 upon leaving, the computer just freezes for no reason, without giving warnings. I have to force the computer of by the power, can't even use the reset button.

I was told from the NComputing hardware/software people that I should do a memory dump of all the terminated processes for each user that is working - that will be 10 users.

How do I do that, freeing up memory dumps, and should I even experience anything like this on such powerful hardware?

Answer (score 4):

One solution from over on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file/408929#408929) *direct quote*:

I've made a script that accomplishes this task.

The idea commes from James Lawrie's answer and this post: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/52375-reading-memory-other-processes.html#post287195

```
#!/bin/bash

grep rw-p /proc/$1/maps | sed -n 's/^\([0-9a-f]*\)-\([0-9a-f]*\) .*$/\1 \2/p' | while read start stop; do gdb --batch --pid $1 -ex "dump memory $1-$start-$stop.dump 0x$start 0x$stop"; done
```

put this in a file (eg. "dump-all-memory-of-pid.sh") and make it executable

usage: `./dump-all-memory-of-pid.sh [pid]`

The output is printed to files with the names: `pid-startaddress-stopaddress.dump`

Dependencies: `gdb`

*end quote*

The only thing to add is a loop to iterate over all PIDs.

Comment: Wel, sound like this can be an answer, but this sound way difficult - will have a look at that link

Comment: @TimBotha - just an FYI, I'm looking at possibly throwing together a simple gui to do this and more.  It may or may not happen though.